# Remove empty object after deleting its properties from nested JS object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a **nested JS object** that looks like this:

```
data = {
    "name": "root",
    "children": [{
            "name": "bob",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "susan",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "chris",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "bobo",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "heather",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I can **delete any property**, regardless of depth, by using the following **recursive function**:

```
function search_and_delete(obj, search_term) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null) {
            search_and_delete(obj[k], search_term)
        } else {
            if (typeof(obj.name) !== 'undefined') {
                if (obj.name === search_term) {
                    delete obj.name
                    delete obj.children
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example:

```
search_and_delete(data, 'bob')
```

...produces the following result:

```
{
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
       {},   // <------ how do I remove this
       {
            "name": "susan",
            "children": []
       },
       {
            "name": "chris",
            "children": []
       },
       {
            "name": "bobo",
            "children": []
       },
       {
            "name": "heather",
            "children": []
       }
    ]
}
```

But this **leaves an empty object** where bob used to be. How can I remove this object as well and reindex the JSON structure as if it were never there?

**UPDATE**

@CertainPerformance answer is the closest but produces the following **error**:

If you use this flare [data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/v1.1.8/test/data/flare.json):

and run the following:

```
search_and_delete(data, "Interpolator", data)
```

It does this:

[image]

Comment: @Tibrogargan no I tried this, that doesn't work. You cannot delete entire objects with Javascript's delete, only the object's properties.

Comment: @Cybernetic use `filter` instead.  You're doing a depth first search which is going to search all the children of a node even if the node should be deleted.  And it's still not a JSON structure, it's a a JavaScript object

Comment: @CertainPerformance JavaScript arrays are sparse by default.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Not at all. Sparse arrays are rare, have to be made deliberately (like with `delete`, or by assigning to an array's index when previous indicies don't exist yet), and almost always a sign of bad code

Comment: @CertainPerformance they are still sparse arrays, even if they have no missing elements.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Arrays which have enumerable own properties of `0` to `length - 1` are not sparse - arrays which have at least one item from `0` to `length - 1` *are* sparse. If no properties are missing, the array isn't sparse.

Comment: @CertainPerformance An array implementation that handles missing elements is a sparse array, even if no elements are missing in an instance of that array.  A logical array that has no missing elements is not sparse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to pass down the parent array to the recursive call so that you can `splice` the found item out of it.

Because mutating an array will change what each property points to, that will make it difficult to use `for..in` - use `Object.values` to iterate over the object (or array) instead:

```js
const data = {
    "name": "root",
    "children": [{
            "name": "bob",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "susan",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "chris",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "bobo",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "heather",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}

function search_and_delete(obj, search_term, parent) {
  if (obj.name === search_term) {
    parent.splice(parent.indexOf(obj), 1);
  } else {
    Object.values(obj).forEach((val) => {
      if (val && typeof val === "object") {
          search_and_delete(val, search_term, obj)
      }
    });
  }
}

search_and_delete(data, 'bob');
console.log(data);
```

Example of using this with a deeper structure:

```js
const data = {
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "value": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "value": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "value": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "value": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "value": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "value": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "value": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "value": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "value": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "value": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "animate",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "value": 17010},
    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "value": 5842},
    {
     "name": "interpolate",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "value": 1983},
      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "value": 2047},
      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "value": 1375},
      {"name": "Interpolator", "value": 8746},
      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "value": 2202},
      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "value": 1382},
      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "value": 1629},
      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "value": 1675},
      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "value": 2042}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "ISchedulable", "value": 1041},
    {"name": "Parallel", "value": 5176},
    {"name": "Pause", "value": 449},
    {"name": "Scheduler", "value": 5593},
    {"name": "Sequence", "value": 5534},
    {"name": "Transition", "value": 9201},
    {"name": "Transitioner", "value": 19975},
    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "value": 1116},
    {"name": "Tween", "value": 6006}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "data",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "converters",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Converters", "value": 721},
      {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "value": 4294},
      {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "value": 9800},
      {"name": "IDataConverter", "value": 1314},
      {"name": "JSONConverter", "value": 2220}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "DataField", "value": 1759},
    {"name": "DataSchema", "value": 2165},
    {"name": "DataSet", "value": 586},
    {"name": "DataSource", "value": 3331},
    {"name": "DataTable", "value": 772},
    {"name": "DataUtil", "value": 3322}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "display",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DirtySprite", "value": 8833},
    {"name": "LineSprite", "value": 1732},
    {"name": "RectSprite", "value": 3623},
    {"name": "TextSprite", "value": 10066}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "flex",
   "children": [
    {"name": "FlareVis", "value": 4116}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "physics",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DragForce", "value": 1082},
    {"name": "GravityForce", "value": 1336},
    {"name": "IForce", "value": 319},
    {"name": "NBodyForce", "value": 10498},
    {"name": "Particle", "value": 2822},
    {"name": "Simulation", "value": 9983},
    {"name": "Spring", "value": 2213},
    {"name": "SpringForce", "value": 1681}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "query",
   "children": [
    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "value": 1616},
    {"name": "And", "value": 1027},
    {"name": "Arithmetic", "value": 3891},
    {"name": "Average", "value": 891},
    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "value": 2893},
    {"name": "Comparison", "value": 5103},
    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "value": 3677},
    {"name": "Count", "value": 781},
    {"name": "DateUtil", "value": 4141},
    {"name": "Distinct", "value": 933},
    {"name": "Expression", "value": 5130},
    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "value": 3617},
    {"name": "Fn", "value": 3240},
    {"name": "If", "value": 2732},
    {"name": "IsA", "value": 2039},
    {"name": "Literal", "value": 1214},
    {"name": "Match", "value": 3748},
    {"name": "Maximum", "value": 843},
    {
     "name": "methods",
     "children": [
      {"name": "add", "value": 593},
      {"name": "and", "value": 330},
      {"name": "average", "value": 287},
      {"name": "count", "value": 277},
      {"name": "distinct", "value": 292},
      {"name": "div", "value": 595},
      {"name": "eq", "value": 594},
      {"name": "fn", "value": 460},
      {"name": "gt", "value": 603},
      {"name": "gte", "value": 625},
      {"name": "iff", "value": 748},
      {"name": "isa", "value": 461},
      {"name": "lt", "value": 597},
      {"name": "lte", "value": 619},
      {"name": "max", "value": 283},
      {"name": "min", "value": 283},
      {"name": "mod", "value": 591},
      {"name": "mul", "value": 603},
      {"name": "neq", "value": 599},
      {"name": "not", "value": 386},
      {"name": "or", "value": 323},
      {"name": "orderby", "value": 307},
      {"name": "range", "value": 772},
      {"name": "select", "value": 296},
      {"name": "stddev", "value": 363},
      {"name": "sub", "value": 600},
      {"name": "sum", "value": 280},
      {"name": "update", "value": 307},
      {"name": "variance", "value": 335},
      {"name": "where", "value": 299},
      {"name": "xor", "value": 354},
      {"name": "_", "value": 264}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Minimum", "value": 843},
    {"name": "Not", "value": 1554},
    {"name": "Or", "value": 970},
    {"name": "Query", "value": 13896},
    {"name": "Range", "value": 1594},
    {"name": "StringUtil", "value": 4130},
    {"name": "Sum", "value": 791},
    {"name": "Variable", "value": 1124},
    {"name": "Variance", "value": 1876},
    {"name": "Xor", "value": 1101}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "scale",
   "children": [
    {"name": "IScaleMap", "value": 2105},
    {"name": "LinearScale", "value": 1316},
    {"name": "LogScale", "value": 3151},
    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "value": 3770},
    {"name": "QuantileScale", "value": 2435},
    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "value": 4839},
    {"name": "RootScale", "value": 1756},
    {"name": "Scale", "value": 4268},
    {"name": "ScaleType", "value": 1821},
    {"name": "TimeScale", "value": 5833}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "util",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Arrays", "value": 8258},
    {"name": "Colors", "value": 10001},
    {"name": "Dates", "value": 8217},
    {"name": "Displays", "value": 12555},
    {"name": "Filter", "value": 2324},
    {"name": "Geometry", "value": 10993},
    {
     "name": "heap",
     "children": [
      {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "value": 9354},
      {"name": "HeapNode", "value": 1233}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "IEvaluable", "value": 335},
    {"name": "IPredicate", "value": 383},
    {"name": "IValueProxy", "value": 874},
    {
     "name": "math",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DenseMatrix", "value": 3165},
      {"name": "IMatrix", "value": 2815},
      {"name": "SparseMatrix", "value": 3366}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Maths", "value": 17705},
    {"name": "Orientation", "value": 1486},
    {
     "name": "palette",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ColorPalette", "value": 6367},
      {"name": "Palette", "value": 1229},
      {"name": "ShapePalette", "value": 2059},
      {"name": "SizePalette", "value": 2291}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Property", "value": 5559},
    {"name": "Shapes", "value": 19118},
    {"name": "Sort", "value": 6887},
    {"name": "Stats", "value": 6557},
    {"name": "Strings", "value": 22026}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "vis",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "axis",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Axes", "value": 1302},
      {"name": "Axis", "value": 24593},
      {"name": "AxisGridLine", "value": 652},
      {"name": "AxisLabel", "value": 636},
      {"name": "CartesianAxes", "value": 6703}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "controls",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AnchorControl", "value": 2138},
      {"name": "ClickControl", "value": 3824},
      {"name": "Control", "value": 1353},
      {"name": "ControlList", "value": 4665},
      {"name": "DragControl", "value": 2649},
      {"name": "ExpandControl", "value": 2832},
      {"name": "HoverControl", "value": 4896},
      {"name": "IControl", "value": 763},
      {"name": "PanZoomControl", "value": 5222},
      {"name": "SelectionControl", "value": 7862},
      {"name": "TooltipControl", "value": 8435}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "data",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Data", "value": 20544},
      {"name": "DataList", "value": 19788},
      {"name": "DataSprite", "value": 10349},
      {"name": "EdgeSprite", "value": 3301},
      {"name": "NodeSprite", "value": 19382},
      {
       "name": "render",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ArrowType", "value": 698},
        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "value": 5569},
        {"name": "IRenderer", "value": 353},
        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "value": 2247}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "ScaleBinding", "value": 11275},
      {"name": "Tree", "value": 7147},
      {"name": "TreeBuilder", "value": 9930}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "events",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DataEvent", "value": 2313},
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "value": 1880},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "value": 1701},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "value": 1117}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "legend",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Legend", "value": 20859},
      {"name": "LegendItem", "value": 4614},
      {"name": "LegendRange", "value": 10530}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "operator",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "distortion",
       "children": [
        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "value": 4461},
        {"name": "Distortion", "value": 6314},
        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "value": 3444}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "encoder",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "value": 3179},
        {"name": "Encoder", "value": 4060},
        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "value": 4138},
        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "value": 1690},
        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "value": 1830}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "filter",
       "children": [
        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "value": 5219},
        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "value": 3165},
        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "value": 3509}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "IOperator", "value": 1286},
      {
       "name": "label",
       "children": [
        {"name": "Labeler", "value": 9956},
        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "value": 3899},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "value": 3202}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "layout",
       "children": [
        {"name": "AxisLayout", "value": 6725},
        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "value": 3727},
        {"name": "CircleLayout", "value": 9317},
        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "value": 12003},
        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "value": 4853},
        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "value": 8411},
        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "value": 4864},
        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "value": 3174},
        {"name": "Layout", "value": 7881},
        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "value": 12870},
        {"name": "PieLayout", "value": 2728},
        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "value": 12348},
        {"name": "RandomLayout", "value": 870},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "value": 9121},
        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "value": 9191}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "Operator", "value": 2490},
      {"name": "OperatorList", "value": 5248},
      {"name": "OperatorSequence", "value": 4190},
      {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "value": 2581},
      {"name": "SortOperator", "value": 2023}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Visualization", "value": 16540}
   ]
  }
 ]
};



function search_and_delete(obj, search_term, parent) {
  if (obj.name === search_term) {
    parent.splice(parent.indexOf(obj), 1);
  } else {
    Object.values(obj).forEach((val) => {
      if (val && typeof val === "object") {
          search_and_delete(val, search_term, obj)
      }
    });
  }
}

search_and_delete(data, "Interpolator") 
console.log(data);
```

Comment: This works at depth 1, but not for deeper depths. At deeper depths all children are removed, not just the one you search for.

Comment: See second snippet, it looks to work fine for me, can you post an example of the input data for which this doesn't work for you?

Comment: Try running your answer on:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/v1.1.8/test/data/flare.json

and do the following example:

search_and_delete(data, "Interpolator", data)

You will see it removes the correct entry, but also the last entry in that group.

Comment: Please see UPDATE in answer

Comment: See edit, the `for..in` was the problem (have to be very careful when mutating while iterating)

Comment: Boom, there it is. Perfect. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Simple filter implementation that uses breadth first search to eliminate processing children of elements that should be deleted.

```js
data = {
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
       { "name": "bob", "children": [] },
       { "name": "susan" },
       { "name": "chris", "children": [] },
       { "name": "bobo", "children": [] },
       { "name": "heather" },
       { "name": "yoink", "children": 
          [ { "name": "bob", "children": [] },
            { "name": "susan", "children": [] }
          ]
       },
       { "name": "bob", "children": 
          [ { "name": "susan", "children": [] },
            { "name": "chris", "children": [] }
          ]
       },
       { "name": "bob" },
    ]
}

function search_and_delete(obj, search_term) {
  if (obj.name === search_term) {
    return undefined
  }
  if (obj.children) obj.children = obj.children.filter( elem => search_and_delete(elem, search_term) )
  return obj
}

console.log(search_and_delete(data, 'bob'))
console.log(search_and_delete(data, 'root'))
```

Using your flare data:

```js
async function getData() {
 return $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/v1.1.8/test/data/flare.json', function(result) {
     return result;
    });
}
$(function() {
 getData().then(function(data) {
  console.log(search_and_delete(data, 'Interpolator'))
 })
});

function search_and_delete(obj, search_term) {
  if (obj.name === search_term) {
    return undefined
  }
  if (obj.children) obj.children = obj.children.filter( elem => search_and_delete(elem, search_term) )
  return obj
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Cybernetic You don't say what version of JavaScript you're using.  You could try `obj.children = Array.prototype.filter(obj.children, ....`, but please supply the version

Comment: V8 7.5.288.30

Also, please see UPDATE in question.

Comment: @Cybernetic no offense, but your question now needs to be clarified.  There is no logical reason presented in your question that explains why only those two entries would be removed, nor what the 3rd argument of `search_and_delete` is for.

Comment: @CertainPerformance figured it out perfectly. Thanks for trying.

Comment: You need to return `obj` in a separate line. Currently, it is returning the array `obj.children` and not an object (I'll delete my answer since this seems better)

Comment: @adiga It's not, it's depending on `filter` which is not available in the version of JS Cybernetic is using - which explains the 3rd argument.  CertainPerformance's answer is better.

Comment: @Cybernetic Ok, so V8 does implement ES6.  The data in your question is not an accurate representation of the actual data you're using.  Elements in that data that do not have children do not have the empty arrays that your example shows.  Simple fix.